# Joining two SQL queries without messing up the counts on both

Tags: mysql

I have two SQL queries, where the first one is:

```
  SELECT distinct count ( xx.PartNumber)  Total,
  xx.doc_no,
  xx.PartNumber,
  xx.PartDescription,
  from WO_RUN AS xx 
  where xx.QA_STATUS = 'A'
  and xx.AddedDate >'12/31/2020'
  group by
  xx.doc_no,
  xx.partnumber,
  xx.PartDescription
  order by xx.partnumber
```

and the second one is:

```
  select distinct 
  count (yy.partnumber) as Total_Parts,
  yy.USER_DOC,
  yy.WO_PARTNUMBER,
  yy.partnumber,
  yy.descriptn
  from VIEW_PARTSTRACING_WO as yy
  where yy.QA_STATUS = 'A'
  and added_dte >'12/31/2020'
  group by
  yy.USER_DOC,
  yy.WO_PARTNUMBER,
  yy.partnumber,
  yy.descriptn
  order by yy.WO_PARTNUMBER,yy.USER_DOC
```

When I try to join them the count on the first query is off. The part number in the first query is the same as the WO_partnumber in the second query.  It is a one to many result Im looking for.

Total   PartNumber  Partdescription  from the first query

total_parts Partnumber Descritn from the second query

So it should look like this

```
Total   Partnumber     Partdescription    Total_parts     Partnumber        Partdescriptn
8      07311P000-02    BALLSCREW ASSY           5        BACB28AT12B030A        Bushing
                                                4        012N8792-45            Nuts
                                                4        BACW10P374L            Washers
5      113A1160-107     Flap Tracks             2        BACN11Z4CD             Nuts
                                                1        113A1240-7FAB          Bushing
```

Comment: Please show how you tried to join them.  Not sure how this can be one to many when both parts could have the same part number more than once?

Comment: Distinct is never useful with group by